# Kafka Follower Fetch is high

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I have setup a 4 broker Kafka cluster on AWS MSK (version 2.2.1). I am monitoring the same through datadog (crawler setup from https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_msk/).

Now as per my understanding, the fetch follower total time is the sum of the other metrics. But you can see all of them <1ms while fetch follower total time is over 200ms.

```
Min.   Avg.   Max.     Metric
486ns  488ns  501ns    aws.kafka.fetch_follower_local_time_ms_mean
204ns  208ns  213ns    aws.kafka.fetch_follower_request_queue_time_ms_mean
192ns  194ns  197ns    aws.kafka.fetch_follower_response_queue_time_ms_mean
100ns  101ns  103ns    aws.kafka.fetch_follower_response_send_time_ms_mean
230ms  231ms  232ms    aws.kafka.fetch_follower_total_time_ms_mean
```

I have not really changed the default Kafka config much:

```
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
log.retention.hours=336
```

Can someone suggest a possible cause of this high follower fetch time and how to reduce it? Any approches to identify the cause are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

FetchFollower acting like "long poll" request. It waits till it gets *replica.fetch.min.bytes* data for replication or *replica.fetch.wait.max.ms* timeout (which is by default 500ms).
So it's basically ok, it's just means that most of FetchFollower requests are waiting for data